# Not able to execute the "Import-module"

Tags: powershell

I get below error when i try to execute the command "Import-module script.ps1"

any idea why is that shows up? what need to be done to resolve the issue ?

```
PS C:\File> Import-module script.ps1
Import-module : The specified module 'script.ps1' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-module script.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (script.ps1:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

Comment: The error message gives clue "was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory". You might want to review [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/module/how-to-write-a-powershell-script-module?view=powershell-7).

Comment: Maybe something like `Import-module C:\File\script.ps1` (or whatever is the real full path to your script)?

Comment: You need to provide the full path of script.ps1. Ex: `Import-Module 'FULL_PATH\script.ps1'`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use .\ to execute scripts, commands from current directory. i.e. ipmo .\script.ps1

> As a security feature, PowerShell does not run executable (native)
>   commands, including PowerShell scripts, unless the command is located
>   in a path that is listed in the Path environment variable $env:path or
>   unless you specify the path to the script file.
>
> To run a script that is in the current directory, specify the full
>   path, or type a dot .\ to represent the current directory.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_command_precedence?view=powershell-7